# How to resolve "IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Tags: python, indentation

I'm running [Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux) and need to pull off a load of commands, but I'm making a script to really speed that up for me. Here is the .py file:

```
import os

if raw_input("Begin fake Access Point? (y/n): ")=="y":
 os.system(airmon-ng)

interface = input("Enter your Interface name: ")
 os.system(airmon-ng "interface" start)
```

I'm getting this error when trying to run it:

```
  File "WNS.py", line 7
    os.system(airmon-ng "interface" start)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Tried to remove the whitespace in the beginning but then I just get this error:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: You have a space at the begging of that line, you need to to be lined up with the line above it.

Comment: Yeah I do that then I get this error: "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Comment: But only remove it before the second one, not the first since that one is inside the `if` block (i.e. exactly as indicated by the error message).

Comment: Pro tip: set your editor to indent 4 spaces when you hit the `TAB` key. With 4 spaces it becomes obvious what is properly indented. Your first `os.system()` line should really use 4 spaces, not one. Your last should not be indented, it is not part of an `if` block.

Comment: @iZodiac: spaces are for denoting blocks. The *first* `os.system()` call is part of the `if` block and should be indented. The other lines should either all be indented to be part of the block, or not indented at all and be executed always as they are then not part of the `if` block.

Comment: Okay that works @MartijnPieters but I get unexpected syntax on "interface" how do I call that interface variable?

Comment: you should be concatenating the strings with `str1 + str2`

Comment: Sorry, @RNar but could you specify more on that?

Comment: @iZodiac: there are other errors; `airmon-ng` is an expression subtracting the variable `ng` from the variable `airmon`. You can't put the string `"interface"` right after such an expression, and the `start` after it is also misplaced. You may want to start with a good Python tutorial here.

Comment: change `airmon-ng "interface" start` to `airmon-ng + " interface " + start` assuming that that is a valid command

Comment: @RNar: `airmon-ng` is almost certainly wrong. If it is meant to be a variable, it should be `airmon_ng`. If it is meant to be a command name, it probably should be a string `"airmon-ng"`. It is unclear from the context what this should achieve.

Comment: Next issue: don't use `os.system()`, the `subprocess` module is a much better tool for running external scripts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had assumed it was a variable he had declared earlier, my apologies

Comment: One-space indent? Come on. Why make it as hard as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indendation is very important in Python. It is used by the interpreter to know how to delimit blocks of instructions.The parameters to the os.system() call don't look good either. Anyway this is how it's supposed to look like

```
import os

if raw_input("Begin fake Access Point? (y/n): ")=="y":
    os.system("airmon-ng")

interface = input("Enter your Interface name: ")
os.system("airmon-ng "+interface+" start")
```

Comment: Okay yes that works but you said my os.system() doesn't look good? How should I sort those out?

Comment: 4 space indentations. anything following an `:` character should be four spaces (or 1 tab) indented from its above line

Comment: @Busturdust: Python expand tabs to the next 8th position. New code should avoid using tabs.